# How to correctly transform JSON into Python objects?

Tags: python, json, json-deserialization

I want to parse JSON I get from a web service into an object structure. Therefore, I am implementing a subclass of `json.JSONDecoder` with an `object_hook` method. I haven't found a good way, yet, to select the correct class for the given data. For classes that have the same attributes, it seems to be impossible to identify the correct one, since that would require to know the key. Let's have a look at an example:

I have the following classes:

```
class Post:
    def __init__(self, title, user=None, group=None):
        self.title = title
        self.user = user
        self.group = group

class Group:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Observe that the `Group` and the `User` class have the same attributes. Now my JSONDecoder looks like this:

```
 class JSONDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):

    def __init__(self, encoding="UTF-8"):
        json.JSONDecoder.__init__(self, object_hook=self.dict_to_object)

    def dict_to_object(self, d):

        if "posts" in d:
            return d["posts"]
        if "title" in d:
            if "user" in d:
               return Post(d["title"], user=d["user"])
            if "group" in d:
               return Post(d["title"], group=d["group"])
        if "name" in d:
            # How to decide if User(d["name"]) or Group(d["name")?
            return None
        return None
```

When it sees a dictionary containing the key "name", it can not decide whether to create a `Group` or a `User` object (hence I return `None` at the moment).

The JSON string I would like to parse looks like the following:

```
s = """
{ "posts" : [ 
    {"title" : "Hello World", "user" : {"name" : "uli"}},
    {"title" : "Hello Group", "group" : {"name" : "Workgroup"}}
  ]
}
"""
```

This should result in a list of Post objects, each having a title and a group or user.

How can this be solved in the best way? Is this accumulation of `if`-Statements in `dict_to_object` really the way to go? (The actual code looks much messier because of the complext nested JSON structure.) Or are there any other patterns or libraries that I should use? (Though I would prefer to go with the standard library.)

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON you want to parse, and what objects you want to parse it into?

Comment: Good point! I added exemplary JSON. I hope the object structure I would like to have is clear now.

Comment: You might be better off doing the object creation "manually" after parsing the JSON.  Then you can iterate recursively through the nested dicts and make use of the keys and values in whatever way you need.

Comment: It helps if you tell us what you ultimately want to do with the `Post/Group/User` objects: will they have any meaningful methods, or are they just clotheshangers for your decode parser. If the latter, you can get away with just one generic JSONObject, a staticmethod `make_obj()` function, and an `iteritems()` method to parse and handle its elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, and IME often with JSON decoding, it is best to assign to a generic dict at decode time, don't use object_hook, and defer creating the individual typed objects until a second pass after all decoding, when you can arbitrarily inspect the stream and the hierarchy you're dealing with, i.e. which object is a parent/child/sibling of what.
(Like @BrenBam says)

***Use classmethod make_xyz functions, not constructors***

`object_hook` often looks seductive but is rarely the thing you want. Just because it's there, it's often the wrong choice.
It's only ever the right choice if you can always know 100% sure which class to use for each object (and even then, only if that is easy to evaluate without passing state around, i.e. writing an ad-hoc parser inside your object-hook), typically that elements follow a certain order, that the JSON is never malformed etc.

Here you are hitting a generic issue: in this specific case a constructor seeing `{"name" : "xyz"}` can't know what type of JSON object it is, only the parent object which saw `"user"/"group" :` can.
One solution is to refactor all the classes and constructors to classmethods `make_group()`,`make_user()`. But that's just lumping your second-decode-pass into your first-decode-pass, for no particular reason, giving us one giant brittle object_hook function. IME that's rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to defer the creation of `User` and `Group` until you have their tags in hand. That is, until you are creating the `Post`:

```
def dict_to_object(self, d):
    if "posts" in d:
        return d["posts"]
    if "title" in d:
        if "user" in d:
           d["user"] = User(d["user"]["name"])
        if "group" in d:
           d["group"] = Group(d["group"]["name"])
        return Post(d["title"],
                    d.get("user", None),
                    d.get("group", None))
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's how I finally solved the problem without inheriting from `json.JSONDecoder`:

```
class JSONDecoder:

    def decode_json(self, js):
        posts = []
        if "posts" in js:
            for p in js["posts"]:
                if "user" in p:
                    posts.append(Post(p["title"], user=self._decode_user(p["user"])))
                if "group" in p:
                    posts.append(Post(p["title"], group=self._decode_group(p["group"])))
        return posts

    def _decode_user(self, js):
        return User(js["name"])

    def _decode_group(self, js):
        return Group(js["name"])
```

which can be called with `JSONDecoder().decode_json(json.loads(s))`. BW: the complete code can be found [on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/bibsonomy/bibsonomy-python/src/tip/bibsonomy.py?at=default).